# removeFromParentNode not freeing memory in ARKit Application

Tags: swift, memory, scenekit, arkit

Hello im very new in working with SceneKit and ARKit so maybe its a basic question. In my ARKit Application I'm trying to shoot some rockets continuously from one point to a direction. Therefore I wrote this function:

```
@objc func shootRocket() {
    guard let cameraTransform = session.currentFrame?.camera.transform else {
        return
    }

    let rocket = VirtualObject(definition: VirtualObjectManager.availableObjects[VirtualObjectManager.availableObjects.count - 1])

    let rocket_pos = float3(x: position.x, y: position.y+0.144, z: position.z-0.66)
    virtualObjectManager.loadVirtualObject(rocket, to: rocket_pos, cameraTransform: cameraTransform)

    if rocket.parent == nil {
        serialQueue.async {
            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(rocket)
            let moveaction = SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3(0,0,-10), duration: 5)
            rocket.runAction(moveaction) {
                rocket.removeAllActions()
                rocket.removeAllAnimations()
                rocket.removeFromParentNode()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And I'm calling this function like this:

```
    if object.parent == nil {
        serialQueue.async {
            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(object)
        }
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.shootRocket), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        ...
    }
```

Everything works except that my memory usage is getting bigger and bigger after each single shot and after a few shots the app crashes.

I though the function removeFromParentNode() is freeing some memory when it gets called but it does not look like.

So what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue as you. Basically What you should do is override the dealloc/deinit function in your Virtual Object class, and inside this function, enumerate over all the child nodes of your Virtual Object and remove them from their parentNode.

Should look something like this:

```
deinit {
    enumerateChildNodes({(_ child: SCNNode, _ stop: Bool) -> Void in
        child.removeFromParentNode()
    })
    print("Object Deallocated =)")
}
```